# Creating charts in MVC returns System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts

I am looking at bringing charts into my mvc app. I have this [MSDN link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart). I don't like the approach used in the section about using a database query as it involves having a database file along with the query in the view too. At first, I tried to gather the data in an ActionResult, save the chart object in my model and then in my view call the `.Write()` method on my chart. However when calling the `.Write()` I get a `System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported` on the `.Write()` itself.

ActionResult

```
DataSet data = //getdata
ChartModel chartModel = new ChartModel();
chartModel.MyChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Status Count")
    .AddSeries("Default",
                xValue: data.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), xField: "count",
                yValues: data.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), yFields: "status_desc");
return View(chartModel);
```

Model

```
public class ChartModel
{
    public Chart MyChart { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@Model.MyChart.Write();
```

---

I then tried to use the Array example and straight copied it and it worked, so I figured it was not liking me have the `.Write()` on its own in the view. So I changed my code to be like this.

ActionResult

```
ChartModel chartModel = new ChartModel();
chartModel.ChartData = //getdata 
return View(chartModel);
```

Model

```
public class ChartModel
{
    public DataSet ChartData{ get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@{var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Status Count")
    .AddSeries("Default",
                xValue: Model.ChartData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), xField: "count",
                yValues: Model.ChartData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), yFields: "status_desc");
 }
```

However this gets the same `System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported` however it is now on the `var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)` line instead.

Currently my code looks like this as once I get the chart working I will be adding other types of charts but reusing the same code.

ActionResult

```
ChartModel chartModel = new ChartModel();
chartModel.ChartData = //getdata
chartModel.ChartTitle = "Status Count";
chartModel.XSeries = "count";
chartModel.YSeries = "status_desc";

return View(chartModel);
```

Model

```
public DataSet ChartData { get; set; }
public string ChartTitle { get; set; }
public string XSeries { get; set; }
public string YSeries { get; set; }
```

View

```
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle(Model.ChartTitle)
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Status",
            xValue: Model.ChartData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), xField: Model.XSeries,
            yValues: Model.ChartData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), yFields: Model.YSeries)
        .Write();
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the current error [image: error]

Comment: As the warning at the top of the doc page says, this article is about the 7 years old ASP.NET Web Pages. Not ASP.NET MVC

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That doesn't explain how it works with Microsoft sample data and not my data

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:

```
var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle(Model.ChartTitle)
        .DataBindTable(dataSource: chartModel.ChartData, xField: Model.XSeries)
        .Write();
```

Comment: Yes I have tried this, except with my code I have to do `.DataBindTable(dataSource: Model.ChartData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), xField: Model.XSeries)` still got the same error

Comment: "I then tried to use the Array example and straight copied it and it worked" - Did you test your last version: 
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle(Model.ChartTitle)
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Status",
            xValue: Model.ChartData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), xField: Model.XSeries,
            yValues: Model.ChartData.Tables[0].AsEnumerable(), yFields: Model.YSeries)
        .Write();
}

with example array?

Comment: The last thing i remember is web.config, that exception could be some missing config